# Digital circuit to compare clock frequencies

Tags: digital-logic, clock-speed

The task I am trying to do:

> Design a digital circuit that takes in two clocks at different frequencies and finds the higher frequency clock. Eg: Say clk0 = 10MHz and clk1 = 5MHz and clk0 is given to in0 and clk1 to in1. The circuit must output a '0' or '1' indicating clk0 or clk1 to be of higher frequency.

My initial approach was to instantiate counters for each input and add a comparator. Of course We will have to reset the counters once one of them overflows and to avoid glitches, load a higher value in the counter that overflowed(like when resetting after overflowing, initialize it to 2 and slower counter to 0 to give a head start.) so that it is always ahead of the slower counter.

But this seems like a lot of real estate, just wondering if there is a smarter way. I remember vaguely reading in university a circuit that feeds one input to clk of FF and one to reset and D being hardwired to '1'. But this circuit results in glitches as the phase,freq of the clocks are random.

Comment: If the clocks are fixed and stable once one counter overflows before the other one you know which was faster. Doesn’t need to be a big counter. Or could be a shift register.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, True, Using counters it seems possible. I'm just wondering if I'm missing an elegant solution to this seemingly simple question.

Comment: @nebuchadnezzar_II In this case the simplest solution would be by a hybrid (not purely digital) circuit. Just few passive components and a comparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the counter approach to detect a frequency difference depends on the difference frequency between clocks.   In your example question the difference is the same so only 2 registers are needed.  If the difference was 1 Hz out of 10 MHz then you would need a 7 decade counter.

Obviously the second case would force you choose a better method like the rate of change of phase difference in analog terms in a few cycles or a faster counter that compares time interval or a PLL.

So in this case how to measure phase in cycles of 5 MHz? well you would expect 10MHz to toggle twice in a 200 ns interval .  There are many ways to compare phase with edge triggered flip flops.  You are looking for 2 edges  vs 1 in the same interval for comparing frequency.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example for a phase locked loop if one clock is the master and assign the other as the voltage controlled oscillator (which will not be voltage controlled in your case.

The control signal which would normally attempt to speed or slow the voltage controlled oscillator by going attempting to source or sink current (it may be reversed (sink or source) - check the datasheet).

A 4000-series chip is the classic Cd4046 phase locked loop.

Of course, this is just one of many options and your idea of using a counter is just fine as well.

Comment: This is a good solution provided the clocks are in the capture range of the PLL